# Sending large amount of data to server

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to send client data around the 60KB to the server. When I put all data in one ajax request, my server reads 20% of the data.

What is the best way to send this large amount of data to the server? I've read that the recommend amount of data per request 2kb is. That means I need to make +/- 30 requests? Or are there any compress methods to use before I send this amount of data?

Comment: There should be no problem whatsoever to send up to many magebytes in one `POST` request. Do you `POST` or `GET`?

Comment: POST. When I save the data, it is like 20% of what the client has send.

Comment: `60KB` is not a lot of data for a request. For comparison jQuery which is a common library on many websites is 80KB after gzipping. Sending 60KB of data to the server is perfectly acceptable, tcp can handle it perfectly well

Comment: Based on the info you give, it will be very hard to debug. Chunking your data in 2kB pieces is certainly not the solution. Without code (both client and server side), server configs, etc, it will be very hard to help you through this forum.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answers. Thought it wasn't normal to send 60kb to a server. But if its normal I will debug then why it reads 20% of it.

Comment: What are you using to make the `POST` request?